# Microsoft Outlook has stopped working Exception code: 0xc0000005

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have an issue after installing a language pack for office now outlook doesn't start after I made the new language the default language:"

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.4351.1000, time stamp: 0x56ba05a5
 Faulting module name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.4351.1000, time stamp: 0x56ba05a5
 Exception code: 0xc0000005
 Fault offset: 0x000260ab
 Faulting process id: 0x1ca0
 Faulting application start time: 0x01d186a14079fe7a
 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
 Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
 Report Id: 7ef4bd0e-f294-11e5-bf44-6002920b5d5a
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This happens every time no matter what computer I try it on. I have already tried running in safe mode and resetting the nav pane. I don't want to have to recreate the profile. Any ideas what could be causing this? I am on Windows 10 Office 2016 TIA

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: Yes, this is for any machine we try this on. Not sure if there is some other setting we need within windows for outlook to work with a different language as the default?